# Upgrade Tridion events from TOM to TOM.NET

Tags: tridion

Is there any guidance or documentation for which classes in TOM.NET replace the functionality in the legacy COM API for Tridion?

I'm having trouble finding the entry point corresponding to TDSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest class you have to the good old TDSE is the `Session` class, which exposes most (if not all) of the "system-level" methods and properties (like current `User`, `WorkflowManager`, etc).

In Event Systems you get a session as part of the Subject - all classes derived from `IdentifiableObject` expose a `Session` property - and this Session will be running under the identity of the user that caused the event to be triggered. In TOM/COM days, this was not always the case, and very often you had to call `.Impersonate` in your code to act as the current user. With TOM.NET this is not required anymore, as long as you use the correct session.

Good luck with your upgrade, the new Event System engine is worlds apart from the old one, there really is no turning back.

Comment: thanks nuno - I'm progressing through my first phase of the [six stages](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/10/you-think-you-got-what-it-takes.html)

Comment: :) Have fun with it, let us know when you get to phase 3, we're all here to help

Answer (score 4):

The TDSE object does not really exist in TOM.NET. The closest object you have is the Session class, although you may not need it as you will receive the target object as the subject parameter of your handler. Try reading this article by Bart:

https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/sdltridion2011eventsystem.aspx

The article has a good overview on setting up the event handlers, and a link to a matrix document mapping old COM driven TOM based event systems to the new methodology of the new TOM.NET based event handlers.

Comment: What is/are the corresponding entry point(s) to the system that replace the TDSE class?

Comment: The closest you have in TOM.NET is the Session class.

Comment: Perhaps you can give us an example of the event of the old TOM based event you are trying to migrate. Please post this in your question, and we may be able to give you some help

Comment: Do keep in mind that TOM is very different from TOM.NET, just like COM is very different from .NET. Don't expect things to "just work" after doing some find/replace in your code...

Comment: @NunoLinhares - can you please add an actual answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Rob Curlette's post about performing an upgrade to 2011.  It discusses the upgrade of the event system:
http://www.curlette.com/?p=90

Bart has also provided a table that maps old events to new ones:
http://sdltridionworld.com/images/event_matrix_tcm89-18738.pdf

Hope this helps get you started!

Comment: thanks nickoli - I've seen both resources already. I'm looking for documentation that maps old functionality to new functionality. Specifically the top level classes like TDSE.

Comment: as Chris mentioned, that doesn't really exist.

Comment: I realize it doesn't exist. I was asking what the NEW class is that REPLACES it. The class I was looking for was Tridion.ContentManager.Session. The remarks say this: This is the entry point to the TOM.NET API. It is used to retrieve existing objects and to create new system-wide objects.
It is retrieved this way: Session session = engine.GetSession();